# iOS 13 remove UIView for simulate status bar background

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, statusbar

I'm working with a `UITableViewController` which when scrolling makes the navigationBar disappear. Now when the navigation bar is hidden when the user swipes the table view the contents of the cells are seen below the status bar ...

To solve this problem I tried to insert a `UIView` to simulate a background of the status bar and everything works but the problem is that when I close the `UITableViewController` the background view of the status bar is not removed from the superview

For now my code is this, can you help me understand where I am wrong? why can't I remove the `UIView` from the superview?

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        setupStatusBarView()

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

       navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.viewWithTag(1)?.removeFromSuperview()
   }


    //MARK: - Setup Status Bar View

    func setupStatusBarView() {

        let height = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0

        let statusBarView = UIView()

        statusBarView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height:height+5)
        statusBarView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        statusBarView.tag = 1
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.addSubview(statusBarView)
    }
```

Comment: its working fine on my end

Comment: before adding `StatusBarView` please check if status bar view already exist or not ... may be you are adding it twice ... and removing once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` get calls multiple times and you have put `setupStatusBarView()` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` that means your background view has been added multiple times and this is totally wrong flow!

You are removing topmost view only not previous ones!

You should set `frame` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and should add the view from `viewDidLoad`!

Comment: in viewDidLoad not Work... Work when I put the Frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews and add the view in viewWillAppear...however your answer is correct ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
let subviewArray = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.subviews
     for view in subviewArray!{
      if view.tag == 1{
         view.removeFromSuperview()
      }
   }
```

Comment: A more appropriate solution would be to evaluate the subviews while 'adding' rather than 'removing' all the copies. Prevention is better than cure, they say :)

Comment: yes, adding that many similar subviews is not recommended way!